# NodeJS async function get(/*db query happens here*/).then(/* need to work with db response here */) not waiting and returning undefined

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

Goodmorning,
First time in StackOverflow so i'm sorry if something is wrongly defined in my questions.
I'm having problems in nodejs working with MongoDB as i'm not able to wait for the results before working on them.
Down you can see that inside the get() function the  variable has the content that i need but then when i return it to the get() and try to print it again, its value is undefined.
Hope you can help me, thanks in advance

```
const get = async () => {
    return MongoClient.connect(url,{useNewUrlParser:true, 
    useUnifiedTopology:true},function(err, db){
        if(err) throw err;
        var dbo=db.db(dbName);
        return dbo.collection("users").find().toArray(function(err,res){
            if(err) throw err;
            db.close();
            console.log("printed inside db call: ")
            console.log(res);
            return res;
        });
    });
}

const test = async () => {
    get().then(res => {
        console.log("printed outside db call:");
        console.log(res);

    }).catch(err => {
        throw err;
    });
}

test();
```

And here is the OUTPUT:

```
printed outside db call:
undefined
printed inside db call: 
[
  { _id: '155e293a-2ac1-4462-bec2-9ae183a1d08c', name: 'fede' },
  { _id: 'f0dddab4-3030-4dfa-b5eb-4c4ded83f161', name: 'fede' }
]
```

Comment: You should put your code in a Code block here so people can quote bits of the code. Anyway, your `get` function doesn't return anything (you don't have the return keyword) and you appear to be using callbacks not promises.

Comment: thanks Stefano, i modify as suggested.

Comment: working to understand the return problem you suggested, anyway, why does it log the "outside db call" before the "inside db call" even if i specified the .then sequence when calling the get() function?

Comment: The reason this is not working is because `get` does not use promises, from what little I know about the Mongo client when you pass a callback function to one methods as the last parameter you won't get a promise back, you will get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved like this**

```
async get(){
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url,{useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true}).catch(err => {
        throw err;
    });
    if(!client){
        return;
    }
    try{
        const db=client.db(dbName);
        let collection=db.collection('users');
        let res = await collection.find().toArray();
        return res;
    }catch(err){
        throw err;
    }finally{
        client.close();
    }
}
```